# Stretch or Change Timing in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I am new to After Effects. I downloaded the free file for the Month of May from VideoHive and have been playing with it. Some of the text is displayed just a bit too short for my linking. I do not want to change the look of the effects but take everything and make it a half second to one second longer. Basically take the length from 35 seconds to about 55-60 seconds without messing up any of the transitions or effects.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution will be found in the Timeline. Scroll through the items in the timeline until you find the track for the text object you want to change. The duration of the text on screen is defined by starting and ending keyframes on the object's track.

Moving the last keyframe on the object's timeline will extend the duration of an object, so clicking and dragging the last keyframe for the text will extend how long it is on screen.